# slang-ism vs slangism vs slang

Tags: word-usage, orthography

I came across the following sentence here in this community:

> It is a slangism for "optimal" or "tuned".

I was about to edit it to the following:

> It is slang for "optimal" or "tuned".

I realized that the following could work too:

> It is a slang-ism for "optimal" or "tuned".

Which of the three is the most correct?  My guess was the second one "slang" since neither "slangism" nor "slang-ism" are words.

Comment: Google Books claims 10,900 results for [is slang for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+slang+for%22), but none at all for [is a slang-ism for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+a+slang-ism+for%22). If you insist on using the article, it's [a slang ***term*** for](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22a+slang+term+for%22) (19,800 results).

Comment: Note that language-related terms that take the suffix _-ism_ include _colloquialism_, _regionalism_, and _localism_. It seems likely that when _slangism_ arose in the nineteenth century, it took one or more of those words as its model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *OED* notes that Greek action verbs ending in *-ιζειν formed nouns with the prefix *-ισμύς*, and that legacy has passed down to us.  Thus when you *baptize*, *ostracize*, or *criticize*, you (respectively) perform a *baptism*, enforce an *ostracism*, and make a *criticism*.  This extends to characteristic actions of classes of things or people, so we have *heroism* and *barbarism*.

There are two other types of formation -- 1) in names of religious and political movements (*Catholicism*, *Conservatism*) and the designation of doctrines (*agnosticism*, *atheism*), and 2) in terms for peculiarities and characteristics:

> *Howdy* is an **Americanism** for hello.
>   "I reckon" is an annoying **colloquialism**

The suffix has give rise to its associated noun *ism*, a collective noun for schools of thought, which the *OED* traces to 1789, as in

> I don't associate myself with liberalism, conservatism, socialism, communism or any of those **isms**.

Tacking on -ism to words and phrases is a time-honored practice, particularly in jest:

> I subscribe to the philosophy of **three-beers-and-shot-per-nightism**

Such usages aren't really meant to survive their expression.

Unfortunately, *slangism* doesn't seem to fit any of these usages, doesn't seem to mean anything other than "slang," and will leave readers wondering why it was coined and used.

Answer (score 2):

Although the word *slangism* doesn't appear in (for example) *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003), it has been showing up in published (and edited) texts for more than 150 years. The first instance that a Google Books search finds is from Robert Bewick, [*The Advantages and Practicability of Applying Co-operation to the Wants of Farmers*](https://books.google.com/books?id=ZrNWAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA6&dq=%22slangism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjO-dy7h7_JAhVX62MKHdSpAjEQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22slangism%22&f=false) (1864):

> All manufacturers can make manure of excellent quality if they would, but not at a low price; and this race for cheapness is doing much to lower the standing of the trade, and also injure the farmer. Some manufacturers have made excellent manure for a few years, and thus ga[i]ned purchasers' confidence; then has come a season, apologising for using a **slangism**, it has been a perfect "sell," and the manufacturer has retired from business.

In all, a general Google Books search turns up 77 unique matches for *slangism*, and narrower, date-specific searches turn up at least several more. It seems to me that *slangism*, while perhaps not in the best of repute, is certainly a word of fairly long standing.

The compact edition of the big *OED* (1971) has this entry for *slangism*:

> **Slangism.** {f. SLANG *sb*<sup>3</sup> 1.} A slang expression. ... [First cited instance:] **1853** *Household Words* Sept. 76/2 Frivolous little foreign  slangisms hovering about fashionable cookery and fashionable furniture.

Neither the poster of this question nor any of the answerers or commenters who have weighed in thus far seem to have had any trouble recognizing the intended meaning of the word, which amounts to "an instance of slang." That being the case, it seems to me that objection to the word relates less to its lack of meaning (since everyone understands the gist of what it means) or to its fundamental nonexistence as a word (since it clearly exists), but to its unconventionality. And objecting to *slangism* for that reason amounts to objecting to it as a matter of style.

I think that editorial wording changes at EL&U ought to focus on problems of meaning, coherence, syntax, or internal consistency, not on points of stylistic disagreement. Consequently, I wouldn't change the original word choice here at all, reasoning that the person who wrote it was probably aware of its status, liked it anyway (or perhaps liked it all the more for that), and thought it was appropriate to use in the particular context where it appears.

Answer (score 0):

While the third one is a valid compound word, the second is by far the most widely used and recognized. I would go with the second choice.

Comment: Should all (or most) -ism's be hyphenated then to be considered "valid" compound words?

Comment: I would suggest not inventing new words when satisfactory ones already are in widespread use.

Comment: @MarkHubbard What are you talking about? I'm not suggesting an invented word.

You can bet I won't be participating on EL&U with you snoots <--- (invented!)

Comment: @gillytech- Sorry, I was actually **agreeing with your answer** and responding to the comment immediately above mine, not trying to be ***slangismistically snooty.*** Someone else down-voted your answer, not me. Please don't leave. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkHubbard Hey not a problem, I was just having some fun :) Thanks for clearing it up. I should have known you were talking about the OP anyhow!

Answer (score -2):

In this case, the addition of "-ism" is almost certainly a distortion of the suffix anyway, because "-ism" means "a belief" or "body of thought" as far as I can recall - e.e. antidisestablishmentarianism! So it's hard to describe a single 'slang' word as that :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to include reference/research to support your answer that says "almost certainly a distortion of the suffix". I would advise you to visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help). Your last paragraph is not necessary.

Comment: You have incorrectly inferred the meaning of the suffix "-ism" from a few examples of its use. Its usage is broader than that.